# Match datasets on a subset of conditions

Tags: r

When matching 2 data sets, is it possible to somehow specify the matching such that an observation from the first dataset is matched to the second dataset if ***at least*** one of the conditions are met?

Let's say I have the following 2 data.tables:

```
dt1<- data.table(c1=c(rep('a', 2), rep('b', 2), rep('c', 2)), 
                 c2=c('x','y','x','y','x','z'),
                 c3.min = c(rep(0,3), rep(-1,3)),
                 c3.max = c(rep(10,3), rep(11,3)),
                 x= (1:6))

dt2 <- data.table(c1=c(rep('a', 3), rep('b', 3), rep('c', 4)), 
                  c2=c(rep(c('x','y'), 5)),
                  c3=c(-1, 2, 0, 10, 11, -1, 3, 6, 3, 12),
                  y= (1:10))
```

I have 3 conditions based on which I want to match dt1 to dt2, and the 3rd condition is a range. If I just do a normal merge by these 3 conditions I will get:

```
> dt2[dt1, on=.(c1,
+               c2,
+               c3 <= c3.max,
+               c3 >= c3.min), nomatch=NA ]

   c1 c2 c3  y c3.1 x
1:  a  x 10  3    0 1
2:  a  y 10  2    0 2
3:  b  x 10 NA    0 3
4:  b  y 11  4   -1 4
5:  b  y 11  6   -1 4
6:  c  x 11  7   -1 5
7:  c  x 11  9   -1 5
8:  c  z 11 NA   -1 6
```

As you can see the observations from dt1 with `x=3` and `x=6` aren't matched. My main concern is to find at least one match for as many observations in dt1 as possible, even if I have to relax some conditions. So I want to know if there is anyway to perform a match where dt1 matches with dt2 on at least 1 out of the 3 conditions?

I could write a loop, but in reality my 2 datasets are much bigger than this (the first has 10K observations and the 2nd has 300K observations), and I have 4 conditions in total, so I'm looking for a more efficient way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct with this type of problem would be to use the [**`sqldf`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/sqldf.pdf) package, since we need to join using `OR` conditions, not `AND` conditions.

```
library(sqldf)
names(dt1) <- c("c1", "c2", "c3_min", "c3_max", "x") # need to get rid of the "."

query1 <- "select * from dt1
left join dt2 
on (dt1.c1 = dt2.c1) or (dt1.c2 = dt2.c2) or (dt2.c3 between dt1.c3_min and dt1.c3_max)"

sqldf(query1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know about this package. It's much more elegant than writing loop after loop!